# MonoAndroid versions - which to use?

Tags: mono, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

I'm a bit confused about MonoAndroid versions related to SDK and JDK.
I'm trying to add Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat but installation fails because it seems that is installing AppCompat 25.1.1 with MonoAndroid Version v6.0.

What is the problem?
This is my Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="HCApp.HCApp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:label="HCApp" android:theme="@style/HCTheme" android:icon="@drawable/Icon"></application>
</manifest>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `installation fails` is not enough information, please tell us what you see to determine that the installation failed